How to use Java 8 libs in Java 11 or later applications?
I need several jar libraries that are build with Java 8 and that do not contain the needed module-info.jar files. But the application's dependencies require at least Java 11 (JavaFX).
Compiling is fine, but I always get the runtime error: "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module ... not found, required by ..."  (... are the module names).
Does anyone know, how to setup gradle (and maybe IntelliJ) that the modules are found at runtime? Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the libraris to Java 11 or higher.
I already tried to add the libs to the --class-path an d--module-path when executing java, but that did not help.

Running a single JVM instance with multiple JDK versions at runtime is not possible. You'd need to separate your project into different modules and run one module with Java 8 and one with Java 11 but that might not be feasible if the dependencies overlap in your classes.

Old Java 8 jar can be used as module, whose name is the name of the jar (except .jar) and which exports every package inside and requires everything. You then need to "requires" the Java8 automatic module.

The problem is that you setup used for compiling is not matching the setup you use for running. This has nothing to do with Java 11 nor modules. You will always run into trouble if you use different (incompatible) environments for compiling than running. You can simply compile your application like in Java 8, not placing it into a named module and referencing the jar files via the class path. Then, run the application by placing it (and the jars) into the class path, like you would in Java 8.
